# Криптографически устойчивый генератор случайных чисел на javascript

Tags: javascript, криптография

Имеется функция, которая генерирует криптографически сложные случайные числа на javascript: Uint8Array, но проблема в том, что она выдает диапазон 0 до 255, как можно ее применить для произвольного диапазона случайных чисел, например как функция Math.random().

Comment: у `Math.random` диапазон не произвольный, а `[0;1)`

Comment: Да, верно. Я просто не уточнил, написал функцию рандома уде подразумевая его масштабируемость)

Comment: Все равно непонятно чем диапазон 0-255 отличается от диапазона 0-1 что его нельзя масштабировать

Comment: Масштабировать то может и можно, однако как это повлияет на его криптографическую устойчивость, не будет ли она нарушена если мы применим математические функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно создать `DataView` и читать оттуда разные типы:

```
const buf = new ArrayBuffer(8)
const view = new DataView(buf)
[64, -124, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].forEach((b, i) => view.setUint8(i, b))
console.log(view.getFloat64(0))
```

Comment: Ошибку выдает: undefined is not an object

Comment: я в firefox+chromium console проверял

Comment: @Mikhail, кто где выдает?

Comment: Пока тестировал встроеным редактором stackoverflow, сообщение syntax error, попробую сейчас еще через firefox

Comment: Вот какую ошибку выдает: Uncaught TypeError: (new DataView(...))[0] is undefined

Comment: вы пример запустили, или уже свой код?

Comment: пример запустил

Comment: и где там `)[0]`